# Why does reactive power lead to (I^2)R losses?

Tags: apparent-power

I read that reducing the power factor increases the current required in the lines (to deliver the same amount of useful work) and therefore increases the (I^2)R losses. Shouldn't the active component of the increased current remain the same and therefore cause no further (I^2)R loss?  Could someone please clarify?

Comment: The point is that reactive power in the load is real power in the distribution system -- there, the voltage and current are always in-phase.

Comment: Hey, not really worth an answer, but a small suggestion/hint: to calculate power dissipated in the wires, what is I and what is V? Remember, the voltage you see across your load has nothing to do with the voltage drop (and its phase!) along the cable.

Answer (score 5):

> I read that reducing the power factor increases the current required in the lines (to deliver the same amount of useful work) and therefore increases the (I^2)R losses.

What is meant by "I²R loss" is the loss across the supply network which includes cables, connectors, etc.

If your system delivers 500 W real power with a power factor (PF) of 0.5 then, assuming the efficiency is %100, the consumed apparent power will be 1000 VA. If this power is drawn from an AC source with a voltage of, say, 250 Vrms then the input current would be 4 Amps RMS. Note that this "current" includes the real component and the reactive component.

Therefore, any resistive components along the supply network (wires, connectors, etc) dissipate power proportional to I² i.e. 16 A².

If the PF was 1.0 then the input current would be half, 2 Amps. So the aforementioned resistive components would dissipate less, proportional to 4 A².

Answer (score 4):

By definition, reactive power isn't dissipated in the end load, but it does increase the RMS current in the feed wires.

Unless superconducting, the feed wires have a finite resistance, and the current involved in the reactive power will lead to resistive losses in the feed wires.  Increasing the power factor will reduce these feed wire losses.

Answer (score 2):

> *I read that reducing the power factor increases the current required
> in the lines (to deliver the same amount of useful work) and therefore
> increases the (I^2)R losses.*

That is correct; a 1 kW load with a low power factor takes significantly more current from the voltage supply (and wiring infrastructure) than a 1 kW load of unity power factor.

It's the increased current from the voltage supply that causes increased \$I^2R\$ losses in the wiring infrastructure.